# Rich text editor for Django with comments/annotation (open source)

Tags: django, ckeditor, tinymce, summernote

Is there anyone succeeded integrating any rich text editor through Django along with inline comments option? I refer inline comment as highlighting a word or sentence in the text editor and adding comments (annotation). When and who commented to be displayed on the side like a thread.
I have tried ckeditor, tinymce, summernote etc and nothing seems to have this functionality without premium licensing. Any leads?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is Slate.js, which might be a lead to try out - [this article written by Shalabh Vyas talks](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/05/commenting-system-wysiwyg-editor/) about all the steps involved in representing and creating a commenting system using the Slate.js framework.

Here is [the source](https://github.com/shalabhvyas/wysiwyg-editor) - if this helps, do let Vyas know with a star or feedback,